# Count Tweets - Twitter API

Tags: php, json, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to count all the tweets that are getting returned from below Twitter API Script. I couldnt find out how to count the tweets that get returned in array json..

Code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIClass/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YYYY",
    'consumer_key' => "XXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "YYYY"
);


/** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/

// Twitter Search API goes back to max last 7 days
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=%24neos&count=100&since=2017-09-4';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$twitter_data = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(), true);

print_r ($twitter_data);


$countTweets = count($twitter_data['statuses']);
echo $countTweets;           




?>
```

Comment: Show us what `$twitter_data` contains ...

Comment: $twitter_data outputs this: https://pastebin.com/BmSyD4xs

Comment: And what exactly is the problem now, what does your count result in?

Comment: Well the count currently outputs "27" which is not right. So i guess i must count some different way..

Comment: And how exactly have you determined that 27 is not right …?

Comment: I've checked on twitter and searched for "$neos", there havent been 27 tweets since "2017-09-4". Only around 15.

Comment: @JonathanMeyer did you search for `"neos"` or `"$neos"` ? The exact reproduction of your search is crucial in this case. Also: Could you provide an example that can be reproduced ? That way, we are able to figure out the problem (if it still exists).

Comment: i searched for "$neos" like i have in my query "%24neos". Hmm What example should I provide that can be reproduced? :)

Comment: Sounds like there isn’t even an actual error to fix here - your JSON array contains 27 tweets, and that’s the number you get when you count them - works as designed. Your _expectation_ as to what tweets your query actually returns might have been wrong however.

Comment: Does my JSON Array really contain 27 tweets?